# How do I introduce a build step into a "mixed mode" vue/asp.net app

Tags: vue.js

We're currently using vue as a script file without a build step. We want to start using webpack and vue-cli. We need to preserve the asp login pages and session handling (cookies) so we need the vue stuff and the asp stuff to share an origin.

The current plan is to ignore the vue dev server, to put src and dist inside the existing .net project folder, and to have iis serve the contents of dist. Is this the way to go? We will lose hot reloading.

If we do this, how and where do I configure the url fragment from the web root to the dist folder? Currently, vue expects dist to be the root of the domain.

Comment: Have you tried creating a project with https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices and see how they do it there?

Comment: That's a really interesting link thanks, but I can't directly use the spa-services stuff because our project isn't .net core. Boohoo.